# Do parameters always maintain their order in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, suppose I create the following procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myDataSet.my_proc(IN var1 INT64, IN var2 NUMERIC, OUT var3 STRING)
BEGIN
\*some statements*\
END;
```

Now, suppose I want to get metadata about this procedure's parameters. So I use the following view in BigQuery `myDataSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`.

I perform the following query:

```
SELECT PARAMETER_MODE, PARAMETER_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM myDataSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'my_proc';
```

When I run the above query, I get the following result:

```
IN var1 INT64
IN var2 NUMERIC
OUT var3 STRING
```

Can I always assume that I will get parameters the order in which they appear in the procedure, when I perform above query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` or  do I need to consider ordering by `ORDINAL_POSITION` column as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `ORDINAL_POSITION` as there is no any particular physical order in which they are stored in respective metadata